# Error while creating angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I want to create Angular project and I get these warnings and errors

```
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated uws@9.14.0: stop using this version
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm ERR! write after end
npm ERR! write after end
```

I have tried to fix these errors by upgrading npm but after npm upgrade, I got the same issues

Comment: this says some of the modules you used are 'depricted'

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to fix this problem, 
I have tried to update manualy istanbul-lib-hook to the latest version but the warning always appears

Comment: What "commands" are you using the create the angular project?

Comment: I used "ng new" for creating project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in same problem. after much try and error, i solved as follows. install yarn.  then run the following code `ng set --global packageManager=yarn`
and then run `ng new project_name`
this way, i solved the problem

If at any point you want to revert back to npm run this: 
     ng config -g cli.packageManager npm